# get the total of the column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created table with json response. and I want to get the sum of the column

```js
const pipeline= [{Geo: "APAC", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 11, pipelinevalue: 1},
   {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 4, pipelinevalue: 2},
   {Geo: "Middle East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 17, pipelinevalue: 1},
   {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 14, pipelinevalue: 1},
   {Geo: "Europe", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 9, pipelinevalue: 2},
   {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1}];
   genetateTable(pipeline,'#geo_summary thead','#geo_summary tbody',pipeval='1');
 function genetateTable(pipeline,divHeader,divBody,pipeval){
                            $.each(pipeline, function (index, item) {
                                
    const $tr = $('<tr>');
    if(pipeval=='1'){
  
  $tr.append([item.SalesStage, item.count,item.pipelinevalue].map(x => $('<td>').text(x)));
    }else{$tr.append([item.SalesStage, item.count].map(x => $('<td>').text(x)));}
  $(divBody).append($tr);
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="geo_summary"> <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff"> <tr><th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th><th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th><th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th></tr></thead> <tbody> </tbody><tfooter><tfooter></table>
```

I want to get the sum of ount and pipelinevalue.

I want to append `<tr><td>Total</td><td>61</td><td>8</td></tr>`

in tfooter.

Comment: What's preventing you keeping a running total of each in your loop?

Comment: I need to print the total in the tfooter

Comment: Ok , that is the goal but you haven't identified where you are stuck doing it. What is the specific problem and question? Are you not able to get those sums, or not able to insert the totals or...??

Comment: I'm struck with getting total I will edit the post with my exploration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const pipeline = [{
    Geo: "APAC",
    SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted",
    count: 11,
    pipelinevalue: 1
  },
  {
    Geo: "NSU",
    SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted",
    count: 4,
    pipelinevalue: 2
  },
  {
    Geo: "Middle East",
    SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted",
    count: 17,
    pipelinevalue: 1
  },
  {
    Geo: "US East",
    SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted",
    count: 14,
    pipelinevalue: 1
  },
  {
    Geo: "Europe",
    SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted",
    count: 9,
    pipelinevalue: 2
  },
  {
    Geo: "US West",
    SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted",
    count: 6,
    pipelinevalue: 1
  }
];
genetateTable(pipeline, '#geo_summary thead', '#geo_summary tbody', pipeval = '1');

function genetateTable(pipeline, divHeader, divBody, pipeval) {
  let totalCount = 0;
  let totalValue = 0;
  $.each(pipeline, function(index, item) {

    const $tr = $('<tr>');
    totalCount += item.count;
    totalValue += item.pipelinevalue;
    if (pipeval == '1') {

      $tr.append([item.SalesStage, item.count, item.pipelinevalue].map(x => $('<td>').text(x)));
    } else {
      $tr.append([item.SalesStage, item.count].map(x => $('<td>').text(x)));
    }
    $(divBody).append($tr);
  });
  $('#geo_summary').append($(`<tfoot><tr><td>Total</td><td>${totalCount}</td><td>${totalValue}</tr></tfoot>`))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="geo_summary">
  <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
  <tfooter>
    <tfooter>
</table>
```

Comment: by using ``  content code differntiation get collapsed.may I use  single quoted instead of `

Comment: I used backticks to interpolate the values of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idiomatic solution without jQuery:

```js
const create = document.createElement.bind(document);
const query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

const pipeline = [
  { Geo: 'APAC', SalesStage: 'Proposal Submitted', count: 11, pipelinevalue: 1 },
  { Geo: 'NSU', SalesStage: 'Proposal Submitted', count: 4, pipelinevalue: 2 },
  { Geo: 'Middle East', SalesStage: 'Proposal Submitted', count: 17, pipelinevalue: 1 },
  { Geo: 'US East', SalesStage: 'Proposal Submitted', count: 14, pipelinevalue: 1 },
  { Geo: 'Europe', SalesStage: 'Proposal Submitted', count: 9, pipelinevalue: 2 },
  { Geo: 'US West', SalesStage: 'Proposal Submitted', count: 6, pipelinevalue: 1 }
];

const totals = pipeline.reduce((totals, { count, pipelinevalue }) => {
  totals.count += count;
  totals.value += pipelinevalue;
  return totals;
}, { count: 0, value: 0 });

const table = query('table');
const trTitles = create('tr');
table.append(trTitles);

['Opportunity', 'Pipeline Count', 'Pipeline Value'].forEach(title => {
  const th = create('th');
  trTitles.append(th);
  th.textContent = title;
});

pipeline.forEach(data => {
  const tr = create('tr');
  table.append(tr);

  Object.values(data).slice(1).forEach(datum => {
    const td = create('td');
    tr.append(td);
    td.textContent = datum;
  });
});

const tfoot = create('tfoot');
table.append(tfoot);
const trFoot = create('tr');
tfoot.append(trFoot);

const { count, value } = totals;

['Total', count, value].forEach(entry => {
  const td = create('td');
  trFoot.append(td);
  td.textContent = entry;
});
```

```css
thead {
   background-color: #00f;
   color: #fff
 }
 
 th {
   background-color: #66cdf2;
   color: #000
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table></table>
  </body>
</html>
```